# Bind an NSArray with NSArrayController and display the results in NSTableView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, cocoa-bindings

I work on trivial core data, non document based cocoa app. There are 3 entities in my core data, and they have one to one relationship.

Entities can be seen on the image bellow:[image]

I can manage to display the values in the console log, but I can't display them in the NSTableView.

Here is my code:

## .h file:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface CombinedViewController : NSViewController <NSTableViewDataSource>

    @property (nonatomic,strong) NSManagedObjectContext *mObjContext;
    @property AppDelegate *appDelegate;
    @property (strong) IBOutlet NSArrayController *combinedRecordsArrayController;
    @property (nonatomic,strong)NSArray *websites;
    @property (weak) IBOutlet NSTableView *combinedTableView;
    @property(strong,nonatomic)NSString *hostingProvider;
    @property(strong,nonatomic)NSString *customerName;
    @property(strong,nonatomic)NSString *websiteUrl;

@end
```

.m file

```
#import "CombinedViewController.h"
#import "Website.h"
#import "Customer.h"
#import "Hosting.h"

@interface CombinedViewController ()

@end

@implementation CombinedViewController

    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        _appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        self.mObjContext = _appDelegate.managedObjectContext;
    }

    -(void)viewDidAppear {
        [self getCombinedResutls];
    }

    -(NSArray *)getCombinedResutls {
        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Website" inManagedObjectContext:self.mObjContext];
        [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSArray *fetchedObjects = [self.mObjContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
        if (fetchedObjects == nil) {
            NSLog(@"Error:%@",error);
        }
        self.websites = [self.mObjContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];
            for (Website *ws in self.websites) {
                self.hostingProvider = ws.hostingInfo.hostingProvider;
                self.customerName = ws.customerInfo.customerName;
                NSLog(@"Website: %@, Customer: %@, Hosting Provider: %@", ws.websiteUrl, self.customerName, self.hostingProvider);
            }

        return self.websites;
    }

@end
```

I have an NSArrayController, named CombinedRecordsArrayController, which in attributes contoller has the following: Mode = Class, ClassName = CombinedViewContoller and both checkboxes are checked, those are Prepares Content and Editable. In binding, I have set the manage object context to file ownder, Model Key Path self.mObjContext.

NSTable is binded with this NSArrayContoller, and if I left only the first column, that is websiteUrl, I get the results.

NSLog line in my .m file, do print the results. However app crash with following error:

[ valueForUndefinedKey:]: the entity Website is not key value coding-compliant for the key "hostingProvider".
Any help will be deeply appreciated. I am struggling with this 4-5 days, and I can't solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Core Data, NSArrayController and NSTableView is easy, if you know how to do it.

Array Controller:
Set Mode to Entity Name.
Set Entity Name to the name of the entity.
Check Prepares Content and Editable.
Bind Managed Object Context to the managed object context.

Table View:
Bind Content to the array controller, Controller Key arrangedObjects.
Bind Selection Indexes to the array controller, Controller Key  selectionIndexes.
Bind Sort Descriptors to the array controller, Controller Key  sortDescriptors.
Bind Value of the table view cell to Table Cell View, Model Key Path objectValue.websiteUrl. Check Conditionally Sets Editable.

That's it.

Comment: I can't do the last step.  I have no table view cell, I have table column and table cell. I can't bind it to table cell view, my options are: file owner, application, ArrayController and Shared User Default...I guess that last step is for iOS, not for OS-X...If you can clarify the last step it would be great

Comment: Just in case that my problem is not clear:  In the nstable view I have 3 columns. Each column, should be filled from different entity. Field customer name is in the customer entity, field providerName is in the Hosing entity and the websiteUrl is in the website entity.

Comment: Update: I found how to do the last step, I had to switch to View Based to do that, but I still do the same error: [<Website 0x6000000a4e60> valueForUndefinedKey:]: the entity Website is not key value coding-compliant for the key "hostingProvider". Read my previous comment please

Comment: You have to use key paths from the Website entity: customerInfo.customerName hostingInfo.providerName websiteUrl

Comment: Yep, that did it. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to generate NSManagedObject subclasses for your data model. If you haven't, load the data model file and look for the option under the Editor menu.

If that's not it, check out the [troubleshooting core data page](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/TroubleshootingCoreData.html) as it specifically mentions your error and a few solutions. Good luck buddy and let me know what works if anything.  4-5 days....I feel your pain.

Comment: No, you don't need to generate NSManagedObject subclasses.

Comment: I have done that, all my entities are subclassed. Problem here is the following: In the nstable view I have 3 columns. Each column, should be filled from different entity.